# How to improve the SQL performance from my Java application

Tags: java, sql, spring, oracle, jdbc

I have this issue:

I have an old big application developed in java (Spring framework). The problem is a sql query that It takes a long time when I do it from the Java application , unlike when I do it from Sql Developer.
From Java It takes around 7 minutes. From Sql Developer it takes 30 seconds. The query is the same from both cases.

The application config is:

- JDK 1.6
- OJDBC 6
- Spring framework 3.6
- Oracle 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0

Datasource config:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="user" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    <property name="initialPoolSize" value="${jdbc.initialPoolSize}"/>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${jdbc.maxPoolSize}"/>
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="${jdbc.minPoolSize}"/>
</bean>
```

Finally, I'm using IBATIS 2.3 for the sql mapping.

I made a test debug, and when the DAO class calls the Ibatis maps (the query) is when the slow performance begins.

Some help?

Sorry for my english.

Regards

Update 1:

The query:

`SELECT  PAG.ID_PAG AS ID_PAG, CAD.CAD_NOMBRE AS CAD_NOMBRE, 
          LOC.LOC_NOMBRE AS LOC_NOMBRE,  EMI.EMI_CODIGO AS EMI_CODIGO,
          EMI.EMI_NOMBRE AS EMI_NOMBRE, 
          TO_CHAR(PAG.PAG_FECHA, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS TRX_FECHA, 
          PAG.PAG_POS AS TRX_POS, RTRIM(PAG.PAG_COMPROBANTE) AS TRX_COMPROBANTE,
          1 AS CANTIDAD, PAG.PAG_MONTO AS TRX_MONTO, 
          PAG.PAG_COMISION_TOTAL AS MONTO_COMISION, PAG.PAG_NETO_TOTAL AS MONTO_NETO
FROM  PW_PAGO PAG, PW_LOCAL LOC, PW_EMISOR EMI, 
      PW_CADENA CAD, PW_TIPOTRX_EMI TTE 
WHERE CAD.ID_CADENA = PAG.ID_CADENA AND EMI.ID_EMISOR = PAG.ID_EMISOR 
  AND LOC.ID_LOCAL = PAG.ID_LOCAL 
  AND PAG.ID_TIPOTRX_EMI = TTE.ID_TIPOTRX_EMI 
  AND PAG.PAG_FLAG_COMISION = 'S'
  AND PAG.PAG_FECHA >= TO_DATE('20160501','YYYYMMDD') 
  AND PAG.PAG_FECHA <= TO_DATE('20160503','YYYYMMDD')
ORDER BY CAD.CAD_NOMBRE, LOC.LOC_NOMBRE, EMI.EMI_NOMBRE, 
         TO_CHAR(PAG.PAG_FECHA, 'DD/MM/YYYY'), PAG.PAG_POS, 
         PAG.PAG_COMPROBANTE, PAG.PAG_MONTO`

Update 2: Here is the Ibatis config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<resultMap id="getPagosComisionesSinGrupoDetalle"
           class="cl.bbr.portalweb.dto.InformePagosComisionesSinGrupoDetalleDTO" >

    <result column="ID_PAG"             property="id_pag"           jdbcType="INTEGER" />
    <result column="CAD_NOMBRE"         property="cad_nombre"       jdbcType="VARCHAR" />
    <result column="LOC_NOMBRE"         property="loc_nombre"       jdbcType="VARCHAR" />
    <result column="EMI_CODIGO"         property="emi_codigo"       jdbcType="VARCHAR" />
    <result column="EMI_NOMBRE"         property="emi_nombre"       jdbcType="VARCHAR" />       
    <result column="TRX_FECHA"          property="trx_fecha"        jdbcType="DATE" />
    <result column="TRX_POS"            property="trx_pos"          jdbcType="VARCHAR" />
    <result column="TRX_COMPROBANTE"    property="trx_comprobante"  jdbcType="VARCHAR" />
    <result column="CANTIDAD"           property="cantidad"         jdbcType="INTEGER" />
    <result column="TRX_MONTO"          property="trx_monto"        jdbcType="DECIMAL" />
    <result column="MONTO_COMISION"     property="monto_comision"   jdbcType="DECIMAL" />
    <result column="MONTO_NETO"         property="monto_neto"       jdbcType="DECIMAL" />
</resultMap>

<!-- Obtiene datos comisiones sin grupo y con detalle-->
<select id="getPagosComisionesSinGrupoDetalle"
        resultMap="getPagosComisionesSinGrupoDetalle"
        parameterClass="cl.bbr.portalweb.dto.InformePagosComisionesSearchCriteria">
    SELECT  PAG.ID_PAG AS ID_PAG, CAD.CAD_NOMBRE AS CAD_NOMBRE, LOC.LOC_NOMBRE AS LOC_NOMBRE,  EMI.EMI_CODIGO AS EMI_CODIGO,EMI.EMI_NOMBRE AS EMI_NOMBRE, TO_CHAR(PAG.PAG_FECHA, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS TRX_FECHA, PAG.PAG_POS AS TRX_POS, RTRIM(PAG.PAG_COMPROBANTE) AS TRX_COMPROBANTE, 1 AS CANTIDAD,PAG.PAG_MONTO AS TRX_MONTO, PAG.PAG_COMISION_TOTAL AS MONTO_COMISION,PAG.PAG_NETO_TOTAL AS MONTO_NETO FROM PW_PAGO PAG, PW_LOCAL LOC,PW_EMISOR EMI, PW_CADENA CAD, PW_TIPOTRX_EMI TTE WHERE CAD.ID_CADENA =PAG.ID_CADENA AND EMI.ID_EMISOR = PAG.ID_EMISOR AND LOC.ID_LOCAL = PAG.ID_LOCAL        AND PAG.ID_TIPOTRX_EMI = TTE.ID_TIPOTRX_EMI AND PAG.PAG_FLAG_COMISION = 'S'              AND <![CDATA[PAG.PAG_FECHA >= #f_ini#]]> AND <![CDATA[PAG.PAG_FECHA <= #f_fin#]]> ORDER BY CAD.CAD_NOMBRE, LOC.LOC_NOMBRE, EMI.EMI_NOMBRE, TO_CHAR(PAG.PAG_FECHA, 'DD/MM/YYYY'), PAG.PAG_POS, PAG.PAG_COMPROBANTE, PAG.PAG_MONTO
    </select>
```

Ibatis map config:

```
<!DOCTYPE sqlMapConfig PUBLIC "-//ibatis.apache.org//DTD SQL Map Config 2.0//EN" "http://ibatis.apache.org/dtd/sql-map-config-2.dtd"> <sqlMapConfig>
<settings useStatementNamespaces="true"/> 
<sqlMap resource="cl/bbr/portalweb/dao/ibatis/maps/oracle/FINDER_INFORME_PAGOS_COMISIONES_SqlMap.xml"/> </sqlMapConfig>
```

Comment: The question is very general and you should at least provide some details. Do you use caching in any form? Have you tried creating a DB index?

Comment: Where's the query?

Comment: If you want to tune the problematic query then please append it to the question.

Comment: Please include the Ibatis mapping xml and mapping class.

Comment: That's a lot of tables you're joining.  How big are they?  What's the table structure? What indices are there?  Did you try `explain plan`?

Comment: Do all these points serve to improve query time in Java? Why from SQL developer it is much faster ? (30 seconds) vs 7 minutes from the application? @AleksG

Comment: Yes I did, I explain plan from Sql Developer and it is fine, the problem is when I run the query from java. @AleksG

Comment: SQL Developer likely only retrieves the first x rows it displays (+ maybe a few screens more) and not all rows.

Comment: Retrieving all rows in the screen It takes around 2 minutes , It remains faster than Java (7 minutes).

Answer (score 1):

Set the `fetchSize` parameter on your select to a large value, e.g. 1000:

```
<select id="getPagosComisionesSinGrupoDetalle"
    resultMap="getPagosComisionesSinGrupoDetalle"
    parameterClass="cl.bbr.portalweb.dto.InformePagosComisionesSearchCriteria"
    fetchSize="1000">
SELECT  PAG.ID_PAG AS ID_PAG, CAD.CAD_NOMBRE AS CAD_NOMBRE, LOC.LOC_NOMBRE AS LOC_NOMBRE,  EMI.EMI_CODIGO AS EMI_CODIGO,EMI.EMI_NOMBRE AS EMI_NOMBRE, TO_CHAR(PAG.PAG_FECHA, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS TRX_FECHA, PAG.PAG_POS AS TRX_POS, RTRIM(PAG.PAG_COMPROBANTE) AS TRX_COMPROBANTE, 1 AS CANTIDAD,PAG.PAG_MONTO AS TRX_MONTO, PAG.PAG_COMISION_TOTAL AS MONTO_COMISION,PAG.PAG_NETO_TOTAL AS MONTO_NETO FROM PW_PAGO PAG, PW_LOCAL LOC,PW_EMISOR EMI, PW_CADENA CAD, PW_TIPOTRX_EMI TTE WHERE CAD.ID_CADENA =PAG.ID_CADENA AND EMI.ID_EMISOR = PAG.ID_EMISOR AND LOC.ID_LOCAL = PAG.ID_LOCAL        AND PAG.ID_TIPOTRX_EMI = TTE.ID_TIPOTRX_EMI AND PAG.PAG_FLAG_COMISION = 'S'              AND <![CDATA[PAG.PAG_FECHA >= #f_ini#]]> AND <![CDATA[PAG.PAG_FECHA <= #f_fin#]]> ORDER BY CAD.CAD_NOMBRE, LOC.LOC_NOMBRE, EMI.EMI_NOMBRE, TO_CHAR(PAG.PAG_FECHA, 'DD/MM/YYYY'), PAG.PAG_POS, PAG.PAG_COMPROBANTE, PAG.PAG_MONTO
</select>
```

The default value for the Oracle JDBC driver is very low, so there's a lot of back and forth traffic with the server.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I tried It but It doesn't improve the performance @kbolino

Comment: For sanity's sake, have you tried running the query from Java using plain JDBC?